# UIAlertController and screen orientation change

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I am using a UIAlertController, with a pop over arrow. When I rotate the screen orientation the popover arrow and the popover are in the wrong place. How do I update its location to the proper place after an orientation change?

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code and a screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orientation change was using a transition coordinator.

I used the coordinator to make sure that the transition ended before updating the actionsheets frame.

```
    func animateAlongsideTransition(in: UIView?, animation: (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)?, completion: (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)? = nil)
```

in the  completion block I then recreated the popover action sheet.